# How to Swap pixels to mirror an image c++

Tags: c++, image

I have a greyscale image (150 x 200) and I need to mirror it about its vertical axis.

The original image is loaded, then I call my function, then I save the new image under ParrotMirror.png.  However with my code the image has not mirrored, could anyone possibly explain what's incorrect about my code? The idea is that pixel element 0 is swapped with 149, and 1 with 148, and 2 with 147 etc...

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "ImageHandle.h"

using namespace std;

int CountBlackPixels (unsigned char PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);

void InvertImage (unsigned char PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);

void ReducePixelLevel (unsigned char PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);

void MirrorImage (unsigned char PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    unsigned char PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];     // Image loaded from file

    // If the file "Parrot.png" cannot be loaded ...
    if (!loadImage(PixelGrid, "Parrot.png"))
    {
        // Display an error message
        cout << "Error loading file \"Parrot.png\"" << endl;
    }

    MirrorImage(PixelGrid);
    {
        if (saveImage(PixelGrid, "ParrotMirror.png"))
        {
            cout << "\nFile \"ParrotMirror.png\" saved successfully" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nCould not save \"ParrotMirror.png\"" << endl;
        }

    }

    return a.exec();
}

void MirrorImage (unsigned char PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{

    for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH; ++row)
    {
        int swapRow = WIDTH - 1 - row; // Mirror pixel

        int col = 0;

        PixelGrid[row][col] = PixelGrid[swapRow][col];

    }
}
```

I have only shown parts of my code relevant to the question, the reason the original image must be reloaded is because there are other functions modifying the image and saving too.

EDIT: This is how my function now stands..

```
void MirrorImage (unsigned char PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{

    for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < HEIGHT / 2; col++)
        {
            int swapRow = WIDTH - 1 - row; // Mirror pixel

            unsigned char temp = PixelGrid[row][col];
            PixelGrid[row][col] = PixelGrid[swapRow][col];
            temp = PixelGrid[swapRow][col];

        }
    }
}
```

which mirrors the image about the centre, so left hand side is half of original image and right hand side half of the mirrored image.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger, or at least performing the algorithm using pen&paper?

Comment: You are swapping only the first pixel in each row and leave the rest untouched.

Comment: how can I solve this? @MikeMB

Comment: Certainly you need 2 loops... Also, you have to take `PixelGrid` by reference.

Comment: @LogicStuff: you are right with the loop, but not with the reference. This is a c-style array which is implicitly passed by pointer anyway. Thats why I hate them so much.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your declaration for `PixelGrid` is somewhat counter intuitive. Usually when you declare a two dimensional array you say something like this:

```
unsigned char array[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
```

This would suggest that in your case the declaration would be more intuitive written like:

```
unsigned char PixelGrid[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

so you might want to look into those dimensions or into how your `loadImage()` function fills that array.

Mirroring a two dimensional array on the vertical axis would mean swapping corresponding columns for each row, so something like this:

```
unsigned char arr[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
for(int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; ++row) // go through all rows
{
    for(int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS / 2; ++column)
    {
        // each column from the first half is swapped
        // with it correspondent from the second half
        unsigned char tmp = arr[row][column];
        arr[row][column] = arr[row][MAX_COLUMNS - column - 1];
        arr[row][MAX_COLUMNS - column - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps me out.  What if I was required to mirror the original image not about its central vertical axis but so it simply mirrored the full original image and not through the centre, would that be much different to this? @lonut

Comment: In other words, reversing the image. @lonut

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "reversing" the image. Do you want to mirror it by both axes?

Comment: [link](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=flipping+an+image+horizontally&FORM=HDRSC2#view=detail&id=6F1DAE4A68A5CC8D7EC57EEB93D9709F35764392&selectedIndex=4)

<<Something like this, but without just flipping the image, I want to do it by swapping each pixel similar to what you shown me earlier. @lonut

Comment: Isn't that image showing exactly what we've been talking about, mirroring the image around the vertical axis?

Comment: As it stands, my modified image is mirrored around the centre, so there is half of the original image and half of the mirrored image, where as I want the full mirrored image. hope that makes sense? @lonut

Comment: And you're doing it similar to the example in my answer? Including the details like going only to the middle column of the image (`column < MAX_COLUMNS / 2`) and actually swapping the values, not only assigning to the current pixel the value of the corresponding pixel from the right side (like you were trying to do in your example code).

Comment: I have updated my post showing what my code looks like, I believe it is the same as your example but with different variable names. @lonut

Comment: Not exactly. This line `temp = PixelGrid[swapRow][col];` is surely wrong, it should probably be reversed, assign the value of `temp` to `PixelGrid[swapRow][col]`.

Comment: When I do that I get a couple errors:                                                            

*collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status*                                 

*:-1: error: cannot open output file debug\ImageTest.exe: Permission denied* @lonut

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code, you probably had the program running when you tried to build it.